# Regex Pattern to Match except when the clause enclosed by the tilde (~) on both sides

Tags: regex

I want to extract matches of the clauses `match-this` that is enclosed with anything other than the *tilde* (~) in the string.

For example, in this string:

```
match-this~match-this~ match-this ~match-this#match-this~match-this~match-this
```

There should be 5 matches from above. The matches are explained below (enclosed by []):

1. Either `match-this~` or `match-this` is correct for first match.
2. `match-this`  is correct for 2nd match.
3. Either `~match-this#` or `~match-this` is correct for 3rd match.
4. Either `#match-this~` or `#match-this` or `match-this~` is correct for 4th match.
5. Either `~match-this` or `match-this` is correct for 5th match.

I can use the pattern `~match-this~` catch these `~match-this~`, but when I tried the negation of it `(?!(~match-this))`, it literally catches all nulls.

When I tried the pattern `[^~]match-this[^~]`, it catches only one match (the 2nd match from above). And when I tried to add asterisk wild card on any negation of tilde, either `[^~]match-this[^~]*` or `[^~]*match-this[^~]`, I got only 2 matches. When I put the asterisk wild card on both, it catches all `match-this` including those which enclosed by tildes `~`.
Is it possible to achieve this with only one regex test? Or Does it need more??

Comment: It's an [asteri**sk**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asterisk), not [Astéri**x**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astérix).

Answer (score 1):

If all five matches can be `"match-this"` (contradicting the requirement for the 3<sup>rd</sup> match) you can match the regular expression

```
~match-this~|(\bmatch-this\b)
```

and keep only matches that are captured (to capture group 1). The idea is to discard matches that are not captured and keep matches that are captured. When the regex engine matches `"~match-this~"` its internal string pointer is moved just past the closing `"~"`, thereby skipping an unwanted substring.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ssw8fM/1)

The regular expression can be broken down as follows.

```
~match-this~   # match literal
|              # or
(              # begin capture group 1
  \b           # match a word boundary
  match-this   # match literal
  \b           # match a word boundary
)              # end capture group 1
```

Being so simple, this regular expression would be supported by most regex engines.

Comment: From what I saw in regex101, it caught all `match-this` (but just divides it into 2 groups) including the one I exactly want to avoid: `~match-this~`. As I said in my question, all forms of `(.*)match-this(.*)` except `~match-this~` are valid.

Comment: Dhana, you are correct that all instances of `'~match-this~'` are matched, however, *none are captured*. We therefore disregard those matches. As I said in my answer, you are only interested in the matches that are captured, none of which are `'~match-this~'`. One regex expert has referred to this technique as [The Greatest Regex Trick Ever](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html). (Search at the link for 'Match Tarzan but not "Tarzan"'). @Thefourthbird has used the same technique in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you also want to match `#match-this~` as a separate match, you would have to account for # while matching, as `[^~]` also matches `#`

You could match what you don't want, and capture in a group what you want to keep.

```
~[^~#]*~|((?:(?!match-this).)*match-this(?:(?!match-this)[^#~])*)
```

**Explanation**

- `~[^~#]*~` Match any char except `~` or `#` between `~`
- `|` Or
- `(` Capture *group 1*

  - `(?:(?!match-this).)*` Match any char if not directly followed by *match-this~
  - `match-this` Match literally
  - `(?:(?!match-this)[^#~])*` Match any char except `~` or `#` if not directly followed by *match this*
- `)` Close group 1

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/i8cA3Z/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/eKsjx9).

Example

```
import re

pattern = r"~[^~#]*~|((?:(?!match-this).)*match-this(?:(?!match-this)[^#~])*)"
s = "match-this~match-this~ match-this ~match-this#match-this~match-this~match-this"
res = [m for m in re.findall(pattern, s) if m]

print (res)
```

Output

```
['match-this', ' match-this ', '~match-this', '#match-this', 'match-this']
```

Comment: From what I saw in regex101, it caught all `match-this` (but just divides it into 2 groups) including the one I exactly want to avoid: `~match-this~`. As I said in my question, all forms of `(.*)match-this(.*)` except `~match-this~` are valid.

Comment: @DhanaD. The valid matches are in group 1 that you can get using re.findall as in the example code. If supported you can use SKIP FAIL like `~[^~#]*~(*SKIP)(*F)|(?:(?!match-this).)*match-this(?:(?!match-this)[^#~])*` https://regex101.com/r/8bDxA1/1

Answer (score 0):

For this you need [both kinds of lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). This will match the 5 spots you want, and there's a reason why it only works this way and not another **and why the prefix and/or suffix can't be included**:

`(?<=~)match-this(?!~)|(?<!~)match-this(?=~)|(?<!~)match-this(?!~)`

Explaining lookarounds:

- `(?=...)` is a positive lookahead: what comes next must match
- `(?!...)` is a **negative** lookahead: what comes next must **not** match
- `(?<=...)` is a positive look**behind**: what comes **before** must match
- `(?<!...)` is a **negative** look**behind**: what comes **before** must **not** match

Why other ways won't work:

- `[^~]` is a class with negation, but it always needs one character to be there and also consumes that character for the match itself. The former is a problem for a starting text. The latter is a problem for having advanced too far, so a "don't match" character is gone already.
- `(^|[^~])` would solve the first problem: either the text starts or it must be a character not matching this. We could do the same for ending texts, but this is a dead again anyway.
- Only lookarounds remain, and even then we have to code all 3 variants, hence the two `|`.
- As per the nature of lookarounds the character in front or behind cannot be captured. Additionally if you want to also match either a leading or a trailing character then this collides with recognizing the next potential match.

It's a difference between telling the engine to "not match" a character and to tell the engine to "look out" for something without actually consuming characters and advancing the current position in the text. Also not every regex engine supports all lookarounds, so it matters where you actually want to use it. For me it works fine in *TextPad 8* and should also work fine in *PCRE* (f.e. in *PHP*). As per [regex101.com/r/CjcaWQ/1](https://regex101.com/r/CjcaWQ/1) it also works as expected by me.

What irritates me: if the leading and/or trailing character of a found match is important to you, then just extract it from the input when processing all the matches, since they also come with starting positions and lengths: first match at position `0` for `10` characters means you look at input text position `-1` and `10`.

Comment: A neat answer. However, I have tested this solution in regex101, it just catches the `match-this` clauses precisely without the *prefix*es and/or *suffix*es, is it possible to catch the prefixes and suffixes of the matched parts?

Comment: Updated. Please link to potential websites and projects done there by you. Yes, you want `match-this` including spaces, but that would be impossible to achieve with an input text like `... match-this match-this ...`.

Comment: In particular, all five of your matches are `"match-this"` whereas the OP does not want that for the third match.

Comment: @CarySwoveland No, all matches are `match-this`, not `"match-this"`. You might also want to free your post from quotation characters - that's the whole sense of using backticks.

Comment: I meant you are matching the substring `"match-this"` five times. I don't know what matching `match-this` would mean as it is not a string.

Comment: @CarySwoveland We have no coding language context here, just text. Hence there are no strings, and with that no begin/end markers are needed to distinguish text literals from number literals. You just add characters to the text with your `"`. Should I also point out you got "_its_" wrong?